# Consolidating data from multiple excel workbook into master workbook and eliminate duplicate append

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck in a problem in VBA while consolidating data from other workbook to master work book and using file name and path name is variable which is changing dynamically in loop i searched but i only find hard coded path so i'm posting here  following is my code.

```
Sub Append()

    'Append data from other files
    Path = "E:\NPM PahseIII\"
    Dim c As Range

    'find the first empty cell in ColA
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
            Filenamenoext = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
        End If

        c.Value = Filenamenoext
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        Windows("Master sheet").Activate
        Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("'Path & [Filename]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5"), 
        Function:=xlSummary

        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

The first problem is that this program gives me the error

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

at this line

```
Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("'Path & [Filename]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5"), 
Function:=xlSummary
```

secondly i want that when first time data is appended by running the code again if there is no change in the other files data then code should not append duplicate again.

Comment: Sure the section `Array("'Path & [Filename]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5")` is wrong. The "Path" and "Filename" should be referring to the variables, not literally the words "Path" and "Filename" - try `Array("'" & Path & "[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5")`

Comment: @jamheadart by changing to your code it's give me error  'Consolidate method of range class failed '?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in that string `"'Path & [Filename]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5"` the `Path` and `Filename` is not considered as a variable but as a hard coded string!

You must use something like

```
"'" & Path & "[" & Filename & "]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$5"
```

if you want to use the variable values.

Also according to the documentation of the [Range.Consolidate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate) the constant of the [xlConsolidationFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconsolidationfunction) is not `Function:=xlSummary` but `Function:=xlSum`.

Also note that `Selection` is very undefined and can be anywhere in that worksheet. I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and reference your ranges, workbooks etc without using `.Activate` and  `.Select` or `Selection.` at all.

Comment: Thanks  Error is gone but data from other files is not consolidating.?

Comment: Are you sure that the consolidate function is correct for your approach? Did you read the documentation about what it actually does? I think instead of that you must copy the data into your master sheet and then use remove duplicates in the master sheet.

Comment: how do i use copy and remove duplicate?also in my current code i need to specify range in the master document for consolidation?

Comment: @HidayatUllah Well that is a way to broad to answer in a comment. You must read [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) and [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) and try it on your own. If you get stuck include your code in a question and give a [mcve] with good example data.